# Estimating risk premium with cross sectional regression

Tags: risk, data, regression, risk-premium

I am trying to estimate a carbon risk premium according to the Fama & MacBeth methodology using a cross-sectional regression approach.
Therefore, I regress the excess return in period t+1 on the size, B/M, and carbon intensity in period t.

Now, I have the problem that my carbon intensity(=carbon emissions/revenue) is data with yearly frequency whereas my returns and size and B/M are monthly data.
Does the approach make sense using the same value of carbon intensity throughout each month of the year?

Comment: Is it the case that carbon intensity data is not available to anyone on a monthly basis, or just you?

Comment: I think it is generally not available

Comment: And also I need to work with the data I have. I am just wondering if it is a problem to just take the same carbon intensity for every month of the year as an independent variable. I have in total 10 years of data.

Comment: It's not incorrect per se, you just need to be prepared for a far less precise estimate by taking into account the massive autocorrelation of the carbon data. (autocorrelation inflates standard errors)

Comment: does that answer your question?